# How to preload a python module into blender console on startup

Tags: python, command-line

I have a set of tools that I use with blender and wanted to know how can I pre-import this module into blender's python console and have it accessible all the time. Just like how bpy works and I don't need to import every time I'm opening the program.

Answer (score 1):

At startup, Blender reads the contents of the `scripts/startup/` directory for python modules and imports them.  You can also choose to use scripts as add-ons (turn on/off via Add-Ons manager):

http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/info_overview.html

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. So I have this module that I don't want to copy into blender's folders as add-on or startup script. I'm trying to write Another startup script or addon that basically tells blender console to "import mymodule as MM" and have it available when I'm working in console. is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Around line 97 in `scripts\modules\console_python.py`, there is some code regarding the imports / convenience variables:

```
    namespace["__builtins__"] = sys.modules["builtins"]
    namespace["bpy"] = bpy

    # weak! - but highly convenient
    namespace["C"] = bpy.context
    namespace["D"] = bpy.data
```

It doesn't work however if you add `import bmesh; namespace["bmesh"] = bmesh` here.

Maybe this code isn't really used, you might wanna check the C code.